# How to run a previous unique command in an Emacs shell (without repeats)?

Tags: shell-command, shell-mode

In Emacs shell, is there a command similar to <kbd>M-p</kbd> but which would skip repeated commands? That is, it would go to the next **different** command. Similar to regular Linux terminal.

So if I were to run:

```
ls
./script
./script
./script
make
```

and press <kbd>M-p</kbd> three times, I want it to go to ls command.

Or, alternatively, how can I define a command like this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The shell you get from `M-x shell` is based on `comint`, so you can
set `comint-input-ignoredups` to `t` in order to get the behaviour you
want. The help even mentions bash:

> comint-input-ignoredups is a variable defined in `comint.el'.
>
> Documentation:
>
> If non-nil, don't add input matching the last on the input ring.
>
> This mirrors the optional behavior of bash.
>
> This variable is buffer-local.
>
> You can customize this variable.

Comment: awesome, exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `M-x comint-dynamic-list-input-ring` and invoked by `C-c C-l`.
 You can also set `C-h v comint-input-ignoredups` to  `t` to see unique commands only in above list.